# How to have more than one app in desktop space?

Tags: macos, keyboard, terminal, spaces

Whenever I click on the maximize/full screen icon on any window, the app window is going to a new Desktop space. But this is kind of distracting because now I am not able to switch apps by doing the <kbd>Command</kbd>+ <kbd>tab</kbd> shortcut..

so How do I have more than one window in a desktop space..

Lets say I want eclipse,terminal and google chrome in a separate desktop space with the ability to see each app in full screen and the ability to switch between apps by doing the <kbd>Command</kbd>+ <kbd>tab</kbd> shortcut??

Can somebody help me on this?

Comment: cannot be done. fullscreen breaks Spaces. I really wish they would fix that. My workaround… never use fullscreen :(

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested now and I'm able to do that (multiple full-screen applications and switching between them with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>), but it could very well be because I'm using [TotalSpaces](http://totalspaces.binaryage.com), an add-on that greatly improves the usability of Spaces.

Note that with OS X El Capitan and later you need to [disable parts of System Integrity Protection (SIP)](https://totalspaces.binaryage.com/elcapitan) for it to work.

Comment: It is still actively developed. You just have to (for now) disable system integrity protection - https://blog.binaryage.com/binaryage-moves-ahead/

Comment: Thanks. I've updated my answer accordingly - I'm still using it with 10.12 and it works perfectly.